# How can a primitive datatype like array of integers have a field 'length'?

Tags: java, arrays

How can a primitive datatype like array of integers have a field 'length', when it is not a class? e.g.

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
int j = a.length;
System.out.println(j);
```

Comment: `a instanceof Object` returns true. You can also `Object a = new int[] { 1,2,3,4 };` as all arrays are Objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple: arrays are not primitives. Rather, they are objects of a reference type.

Another way to experience this is to see what happens if you pass an array of int into a method and modify the contents of the array from within the method. You'll see that this will modify the original array object too, as would happen to all variables of reference type (non-primitive).

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly make 'a' to seem as an object reference, i mean here it seems as a primitive having a reference of types 'int'!

Comment: but it is still a VM "hack", similar like the `class` "attribute" of a class.

Comment: @Ashwyn: the array is like an empty egg carton. Don't confuse it with the eggs -- with what it contains!

Answer (score 3):

> How can a primitive datatype like array of integers have a field 'length', when it is not a class?

Other answers have explained that arrays are not primitive data types in Java.

While an array type is not declared as a class, it is in many respects *like* a class.  For instance:

- every array type has `java.lang.Object` as its implicit superclass,
- array instances are denoted by references, and can (in most cases) hold state,
- array types have methods; i.e. the methods declared by `Object`, and
- you can call `getClass()` on an array instance to get its `Class` object.

If you think about these, it its not semantically inconsistent for an array to have some state that holds the size of the array.

---

The Java language designers decided that the length of an array should be modelled as a read-only field called `length` whose type is `int`.  That's what it looks like (per the language syntax), and that's how it behaves.

The "different-ness" of the "length" field is only apparent at the implementation level:

- the `length` field is a represented in the object header for an array object, and
- there is a special bytecode for accessing the length of an array object (ARRAYLENGTH - bytecode 190)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects of reference type and not primitives.

Comment: length is a method? Are you sure?

Comment: length is not a method, rather it is a field; had it been a method, it's syntax would have been length(). length() on the other hand is a method if we are dealing with Strings!